# How to run a PHP script / function on shared hosting so that it doesn't time out?

Tags: php, shared-hosting

I have a website on shared hosting, that I would like to run some reports on 
eg. performance, maybe send emails to all "non activated account", or report about their account to users.

So the issue is obvious if I just hit a URL some of these scripts will definitely time out and not finish.

I am not sure how to approach this problem, I have no access to SSH so I can't execute it via command line.

What are my other options? And if you can direct me in a way where I will be able to learn this.

Answer (score 1):

You could set `max_execution_time`, and memory_limit via ini_set(), since they are both `PHP_INI_ALL`. On the top of your script write this:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time',200); //in seconds
ini_set('memory_limit', "100M"); //in megabytes, change to your needs
```

For unlimited use, remove limits, use with caution, preferably for debugging only:

- memory_limit set to `-1`
- max_execution_time set to `0`

Note that this setting will only affect your current PHP script, not other scripts, and it won't affect your database timeouts, or anything else you are doing there.

Comment: Thanks I will try it, do you know if there is something I can do along the lines of a cron job? For example HIT URL, and it will start the CJ and when finished it will eg. email me results ?

Comment: at the end of the script, or on a condition use PHP's `mail()`function